# How to set naming strategy using Spark DataFrames and Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I have case classes that use lowerCamelCase variable name convention.
Cassandra uses lower_underscore convention for rows and table names.
Is there a way to instruct DataFrame to convert names automatically?

**Table definition**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_storage.dummy (
  some_name text,
  some_value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (some_name)
);
```

**Spark code**:

```scala
val ds = List(Dummy("key", 1)).toDS()

ds.write
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .option("keyspace", "data_storage")
    .option("table", "dummy")
    .save
```

I wrote a function that changes names from camel to underscore and vice versa, but It isn't working when in a case when **some** legacy case classes also use lower_underscore naming convention.

```scala
  private def toUnderscore(ds: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    normalizeNames(ds, CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE)
  }

  private def toCamel(ds: DataFrame): DataFrame =
    normalizeNames(ds, CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL)

  private def normalizeNames(df: DataFrame, from: CaseFormat, to: CaseFormat): DataFrame = {
    def normalizeName(c: String): String = from.to(to, c.toString)

    def flattenSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
      StructType(schema.fields.map {
        case StructField(name, inner: StructType, nullable, metadata) =>
          StructField(normalizeName(name), flattenSchema(inner), nullable, metadata)
        case StructField(name, array: ArrayType, nullable, metadata)  =>
          StructField(
            normalizeName(name), array.copy(elementType = array.elementType match {
              case s: StructType => flattenSchema(s)
              case x             => x
            }), nullable, metadata)
        case StructField(name, flat, nullable, metadata)              =>
          StructField(normalizeName(name), flat, nullable, metadata)
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no built in methods for this kind of name conversion. The RDD interface has some additional methods around it's type conversion that do these kind of conversions but in general we didn't add a mechanism for DataSets/DataFrames.